# JProfiler - how to profile remote application when there is firewall?

Tags: proxy, firewall, putty, jprofiler, tunneling

I successfully managed to install the JProfiler remote probe and I see it running in 'catalina.out' (Tomcat). The only problem is that all ports on the remote machine are firewalled (except for 80 and 8080) and no matter which port I chose, the JProfiler GUI can't connect to the remote probe.

I tried to use PuTTY tunneling but I'm not really sure how to set up the tunneling rules. Moreover, it seems that there are no 'network preferences' in JProfiler where I can specify SOCKS proxy.

How can I overcome this problem without bothering the firewall rules? The remote machine is not in my direct control and it takes a lot of time and paperwork to open additional ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution which involves several steps.

**Step 1**: Create proper SOCKS tunneling:

[image: PuTTY proxy settings for JProfiler when profiling remote application with firewall.]

Don't forget to click the 'Add' button in the end.

**Step 2**: Modify the JProfiler's startup script and add the SOCKS proxy settings:

```
java -Xmx512m -classpath "%LOCALCLASSPATH%" -DsocksProxyHost=localhost -DsocksProxyPort=8849 com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication
```

The above code snippet should be placed in **jprofiler.bat** which is located here:

**\Program Files\jprofiler8\bin\windows**

**Step 3**: Open remote JProfiler session and use the original **remote host** and the original **remote port**. In other words, start normal remote profiling session with no deviations from the original process. The PuTTY tunneling will take care of the firewall problem for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing with SSH (using Cygwin on Windows):

```
ssh -L 8849:localhost:8849 <username>@<target-hostname>
```

Since it is not a privileged port, you can login as a standard user.

Then I can connect the JProfiler GUI to port 8849 on the local Windows machine.

BTW, I also use jpenable on the target to expose the profiling agent without modifying the application server start/config files:

```
jpenable --pid=<app-server-pid> --noinput --gui --port=8849
```